# php arrays create parenthood array

Tags: php, arrays, hierarchy

I have two arrays:

Parents:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Levi Self
    [2] => Portraits
    [3] => Abstract
)
```

Children:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Portraits
    [1] => Abstract
    [2] => Megan
    [3] => Locks
)
```

And I'm trying to build an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [Levi Self] => Array
      (
          [0] => Portraits
          [1] => Abstract
      )

    [Portraits] => Array
      (
          [0] => Megan
      )

     [Abstract] => Array
      (
          [0] => Locks
      )
)
```

I am getting the hierarchy from the database table that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Portraits
            [parent] => Levi Self
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Abstract
            [parent] => Levi Self
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Megan
            [parent] => Portraits
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => Locks
            [parent] => Abstract
        )

)
```

Am I trying something that is impossible?
Thanks, Levi Self

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach ($that_last_array_of_yours as $arr) {
  $result[$arr['parent']][] = $arr['title'];
}

print_r($result);
```